# Rerender a functional React component using useState and ensure useEffect hook executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional React component which draws a polygon on a canvas. The result looks like this:

[image]

My code is (I have left out the irrelevant stuff):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Plot(props) {
  const [localPolygon, setlocalPolygon] = useState(props.polygon);

  useEffect(() => {
    // in here get the canvas context
    const { context } = getContext();
    // transforms data and draw the polygon on the canvas canvas
  }, [localPolygon]);

  const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    // making some changes here to localPolgon as user drag
    // then update localPolygon
    setLocalPolygon(localPolygon);
    // I now expect the polygon to change position, but it does not
  };

  return (
    <>
      {" "}
      <canvas
        className="canvas"
        onMouseMove={(e) => {
          let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
          handleMouseMove(nativeEvent);
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default Plot;
```

So the component loads, and in `useEffect` I do some transformation of data and draw it on the canvas. This works fine. I now want to drag the polygon. I'm able to get the new coordinates as I drag, and update `localPolygon` with `setLocalPolygon(localPolygon)`. I can see it getting updated, but the polygon is not changing position because the component does not seem to re-render - and `useEffect` is not called, which is what will update the canvas. You can see I have `localPolygon` as the second param in `useEffect`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what type local polygon is, but I guess the problem is related to "shallow comparison"

Comment: localPolygon is an object that holds an array of array of points...

Comment: Deep clone localpolygon before passing it to the state. This way the change will be detected